# ORA-00905: missing keyword for select into

Tags: sql, oracle

i am trying this

```
SELECT 'LL' 
INTO IPA_PRCADJ_HDR(IPAPH_REMARKS)
FROM DUAL;
```

but showing an error `ORA-00905: missing keyword'

Comment: what is LL? isn't it should be a field name?

Comment: select ... into ... can only be used in PLSQL not in SQL. So you are either using it incorrectly or you need to show us your PLSQL code.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve in here? insert the remark 'LL' into PA_PRCADJ_HDR(IPAPH_REMARKS)????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If IPA_PRCADJ_HDR already exists then ...

```
insert into IPA_PRCADJ_HDR select * from DUAL
```

If you want to create IPA_PRCADJ_HDR based on the records in DUAL...

```
create table IPA_PRCADJ_HDR as select * from DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

IPA_PRCADJ_HDR(IPAPH_REMARKS) must be a container like varchar or number to store 'LL'. If u running your query in store procedure, declare IPA_PRCADJ_HDR(IPAPH_REMARKS) as container and you can use INTO command else you are using it in a wrong way